# Reduce memory footprint of File operations

Tags: c#, file-io, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm trying to run this method, it works fine but every time after some hundreds of internal iterations I get with an Out of Memory exception:

```
...
MNDBEntities db = new MNDBEntities();
var regs = new List<DOCUMENTS>();
var query = from reg in db.DOCUMENTS
            where reg.TAG_KEYS.Any(p => p.TAG_DATE_VALUES.FirstOrDefault().TAG_DATE_VALUE.HasValue 
                && p.TAG_DATE_VALUES.FirstOrDefault().TAG_DATE_VALUE.Value.Year == 2012)
            select reg;

var pages = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Document cert = new Document();

    var tags = item.TAG_KEYS;
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        // Basic stuff...
    }

    var pagesS = item.PAGES;
    foreach (var page in pagesS)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Kumquat\" + (int)page.NUMBER + ".vpimg";
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, page.IMAGE);
        pages.Add(path);
        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }

    //cms.Save(cert, pages.ToArray()).Wait();
    foreach (var pageFile in pages)
        File.Delete(pageFile);

    pagesS = null;
    pages.Clear();
}
...
```

I'm pretty sure problem is related with the File.WriteAllBytes or the File.Delete because if I comment those lines the method runs without exception. What I'm doing is basically get some tags from a DB plus a document image, that image is then saved onto disk then a stored into a cms and then deleted from disk. Honestly don't figure out what I'm doing wrong with that File calls. Any idea?

This is what PerfView shows:

[image: PerfView of the method]

This is what visual studio 2012 profiler shows as the hot point, the thing is: this is all generated code (within the Entity Model) am I doing something wrong maybe with the properties of the model?

[image]

Comment: Your `db` should be in a `using`, yes? Any other `IDisposable` classes in play here? Maybe `Document`?

Comment: Roughly how many records are returned with your query and about how large is the `IMAGE` for each of the records?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you've found a leak in `WriteAllBytes`, and `File.Delete` hardly allocates memory (so to speak). You need to look at how you are instantiating your data and maybe implement some kind of disposal pattern to ensure you don't run out of memory. However, without knowing what 'cms' is or exactly what kind of data you're pulling from your DB it's difficult to recommend something specific.

Comment: Probably an object with the IDisposable interface that is not properly disposed. Concider enclosing the inner body of your foreach into a "using" or simply call the Dispose method on each of them when continuing through the loop

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes. It's enclosing by one. Document is a plain class not disposable (a few string variables).

Comment: @vane query returns 57980 rows for documents and 113379 pages.

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul is it 113379 pages per row or is that a total number of all pages in all rows? Also, what is the average size in bytes of `IMAGE`? Let's just say for example the average image size if 500k, that means that about 57 gigs of memory is being (attempted to be) allocated!

Comment: @vane 113379 is the total amount of images. Each document has approx. 2 images and the average image size is 270k. The thing is, independently of the size, why does the entity framework try to allocate that memory given that I'm disposing those bytes on each iteration?

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul well, you're getting the rows to iterate through to begin with and the `IMAGE` is part of those rows so it needs to allocate that memory to hold all those `IMAGE`s. Even though you dispose of them after you use each one, you're still starting with a huge allocation... roughly 31 gigs worth of images stored in memory; this is of course unless I'm completely misunderstanding your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567 to profile your code, focusing on GC events, and CLR managed allocation tick events.

page.IMAGE could be the problem. Most likely it will allocate a byte array and never delete it. Best to change the code to:

```
page.WriteTo(path);
```

The rest of the code shown does look fine. The only possible problem is large object allocation, which could lead to fragmentation problem in [LOH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).

Comment: Feng Page.IMAGE is a byte[] and there's no page.WriteTo that's precisely what File.WriteAllBytes(path, page.IMAGE); is doing. I'll try with your suggested tool and will post.

Comment: After pretty hard work you're right. It was a problem related with instance creation of large byte arrays (within the LOH). I changed the code property removing the nested entity framework code and replacing it with custom native SQL. Sorry for the initial downvote, didn't understand your response at the beginning. +1 and accepted. Thank you, very much.